# Solr - store multiple Word documents for a single unique ID

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

We'd like to index and store a group of Word documents in Solr and have them appear as elements of a multivalued text field, with the content of each appearing as an  element under that one entry in the index. In other words, it looks like this

- ID

  - abcdef [text of Word_1.docx]
  - xyzabc [text of Word_2.docx]
  - efghij [text of Word_3.docx]

We don't want each document indexed to have its own unique ID; a group of documents will be children of a particular ID. There can be any number of documents for that ID. 
How to do this?

**UPDATE:** Here's my C# code; how would I read multiple documents into this for the unique ID being set with the `(++count).ToString()`?

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
{

    solr.Extract(
        new ExtractParameters(fileStream, (++_count).ToString())
            {
                ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                ExtractOnly = false,
                Fields = new List<ExtractField>()
                                                 {
                                                     new ExtractField("action", actionTo),
                                                     new ExtractField("actiondate", actionDate),
                                                     new ExtractField("abstract", abstract),
                                                     new ExtractField("docval", docval),
                                                     new ExtractField("documentgeo",documentgeo),
                                                     new ExtractField("filename", filename),
                                                     new ExtractField("isprimary", IsPrimary.ToString())
                                                 },
                                    AutoCommit = true 
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/solrnet/DuHv0EGK_y4/discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SOLR schema define two fields - `id` and `text`. `text` should be multivalued. Then aggregate in your `SolrInputDocument`s the text data for the id and index.

```
<field name="id" type="int" multiValued="false" stored="true" indexed="true" />
<field name="text" type="text" multiValued="true" stored="true" indexed="true" />
```

I don't know the `c#` API, but using SolrJ it is fairly easy to aggregate using `SolrInputDocument.addField("fieldname", "value")`.

**Example update**

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", 1)
for (String docText : documents){
    doc.addField("text", docText)
}
```

**Example .NET update**

I would define my class in the following way:

```
public class Document{
[SolrUniqueKey("id")]
public integer Id { get; set; }

[SolrField("text")]
public ICollection<string> texts { get; set; }
```

Then I will populate it and submit with something like this pseudo-.NET code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
for (String documentPath : paths) {
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path)) {
        string id = fileStream.getId();
        if (doc.getId() == id){
            doc.getTexts.add(fileStream.getText())
        }
    }
}
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Document>>();
solr.Add(doc);
solr.Commit();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the code, but this doesn't take into account the multiple documents to be indexed. How do you use the `SolrInputDocument.addField()` method? Are you adding a new field to the schema in code? Also, I can't find the equivalent syntax for this in SolrNet.

Comment: The SolrNet examples are at http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/CRUD I would also recommend you look at the SampleApp in the SolrNet Source - https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/SampleSolrApp

Comment: Thanks, Paige. From the documentation, SolrNet doesn't seem to support this. Or the docs don't mention it.

Comment: As far as I can understand the .NET code you define your own Objects and _annotate_ some of their properties with solr field definitions. You could just annotate a collection of strings object with `[SolrField("text")]` I guess.

Comment: Thanks, kpentchev. Very intriguing! But then, how do you pass in the multiple documents for the same ID? Please see my update above that includes `Filestream` object.

Comment: I added a new code sample. I used the example at http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/BasicUsage2 to write it down.